# emulate a web browser on my website

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, http-proxy

Is it possible to create website which contains something like mini web browser?

- It shoulbe be able to allow you to browse Internet without leaving the site.
- Also it should replace all of the images within with an image of my choice.

[this is how it supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyJph.jpg)

I tried to implement this via iframes and works kinda, but there are few major issues with it.The main problem is that I can't edit the content of the webpage inside iframe due to same-origin policy and there are few major websites like google and facebook that don't premit viewing them in ifarme. Are there any workarounds for these limitation or should use something else instead of iframe? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: No. For exactly the security reasons you mentioned. Imagine if a malicious person could just wrap your bank's website in their own "mini web browser" and change anything they wanted to.

Comment: @Jack click the check mark by the answer if it answer your question. You need 50 rep points to comment and participating in this site will help you get those points. If you still have anymore questions or my answer does not sum it up edit your question and I will try to clear it up for you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you will want to setup a proxy server.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-proxy-server/12890/) for you setting one up using google app engine.

Here is an example of a [live one](https://www.proxysite.com/) for you to use for better understanding

What is a proxy server you say?

> In computer networks, a proxy server is a server (a computer system or
>   an application) that acts as an intermediary for requests from clients
>   seeking resources from other servers.[1](http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-proxy-server/12890/) A client connects to the
>   proxy server, requesting some service, such as a file, connection, web
>   page, or other resource available from a different server and the
>   proxy server evaluates the request as a way to simplify and control
>   its complexity. Proxies were invented to add structure and
>   encapsulation to distributed systems.[2](https://www.proxysite.com/) Today, most proxies are web
>   proxies, facilitating access to content on the World Wide Web and
>   providing anonymity.

This is a cool way for people in China to browse the web because proxy sites can help them slip past the dictators blocking their internet!

In my case, once upon a time I sold cars. The evil overlords of the car dealership I worked for tried to censor the internet. Blocking us from the wonderful things us measly car salesman would enjoy looking at when there was not any people to con into buying cars. So I would browse for proxy websites that were not blocked by the overlords allowing me to browse the wonderful internet freely without any dictatorships blocking me!

As shown in your image you want it to look exactly like it looks as in this proxy site,

Image one before you browse to a URL.

[image]

Image 2 after you add a URL notice your still in the same page with the URL at the top as shown in your image.

[image]